# Proxy external images with nginx

Tags: image, proxy, nginx

Is there a way to proxy external images with nginx without downloading and storing them locally ? I.e. passing image's `URI` to my proxy server like this :

```
`http://myproxydomain.com/http://example.com/image.jpg`
```

And including this `URI` in the `src` attribute for images on my site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- this is possible:

```
    merge_slashes off;

    location ~ /(?<r>http://.*) {
        resolver 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_pass $r;
    }
```

Whether you should do it is another matter.  Having `merge_slashes off` may not be a good idea.